# UNAVAILABLE: Keepalive failed. The connection is likely gone

Tags: android, grpc, grpc-java

I am using grpc-okhttp on an Android application for RPC calls to a backend.

This is the client side keep-alive configuration:

```
.keepAliveTime(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.keepAliveTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.keepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
```

I have observed cases where the connection dies at some point but is never restored until app restart.

I have not found a way to consistently reproduce it yet but in production I'm seeing a lot of errors "UNAVAILABLE: Keepalive failed. The connection is likely gone".

From my understanding gRPC should reconnect automatically but it looks like once the keep-alive fails once, it never even bothers to reconnect - following requests fail immediately, not even waiting for a deadline or keep-alive timeout.

Comment: Have you tried [`AndroidChannelBuilder`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.grpc/grpc-android/1.32.2/io/grpc/android/AndroidChannelBuilder.html)? It has better network monitoring on Android that can respond more quickly to network changes.

Comment: I have not. It looks promising. Will give it a go. Thanks!

Comment: @voidzcy if you post an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sure, glad to hear my suggestion helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely caused by delayed/failed discovery of network state changes on Android devices. gRPC provides [`AndroidChannelBuilder`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.grpc/grpc-android/1.32.2/io/grpc/android/AndroidChannelBuilder.html), which is trying to address this problem particularly. It uses Android [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing) to receive network state updates and can respond more quickly to network changes.

Comment: Unfortunately looks like the issue is only partly resolved. There are still cases where the connection is gone and doesn't get reset.

Comment: Can you describe the scenario of what actually happens? We've seen other users saying RPCs fail at the moment network **recovers** (see [grpc-java#5610](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5610)).

Comment: From the production logs I have discovered that users disconnect from the wifi network that the server is on, then at some point get back on it, but the connection is already gone and is not renegotiated. This results in them repeatedly trying an action that makes a call to the server, but erroring with "UNAVAILABLE: Keepalive failed. The connection is likely gone" or just "UNAVAILABLE". The error is thrown immediately after initiating the request, so it looks like gRPC isn't even trying to reconnect at that point.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what [grpc-java#5610](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5610) was opened for. Normally gRPC has automatic reconnect with exponential backoff. With AndroidChannelBuilder, it resets the backoff immediately when the Android ConnectivityManager notifies the recovery of network. However, there is a race between new RPCs are made and reconnect successfully. If the former happens first, RPCs fail immediately. We're probably going to fix this to buffer new calls while the channel is reconnecting in next release. It would be an easy fix if no other implications involved.

Comment: In my case the reconnect never happens, so I'm not sure it's the same issue. The user keeps trying the action and it always fails immediately, until they restart the app. I suspect it could possibly have something to do with the different conditions under which the network state change happens - like app being in background, phone in standby, connected to a different wifi, etc. Although my app has a foreground service to ensure it's always running.

Comment: There should always be reconnect (may with backoff), even the channel is not built from AndroidChannelBuilder. How did you verify the reconnect never happened? Also, how did you ensure the network had recovered? 

In [grpc-java#5610](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5610#issue-434262247), one of the users was using an OkHttpClient in parallel to see the network does have recovered.

If you are experiencing something different while you are sure there is network, please open a new issue on grpc-java github repository.